# Run composer using different version of PHP without changing the environment variables

Tags: php, composer-php

I have multiples projects, some of them work with PHP 5.6 and other with PHP 7.1. To work with both projects simultaneously I have to change environment variables each time when I have to run Composer.

Is there a way to run `composer` command and tell to use the version of PHP I want? Like:

```
composer install -php=5.6
```

Comment: Composer is just a phar archive.   `/path/to/php5.6 /path/to/composer install`

Comment: Another solution is to use phpbrew: https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`platform`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) setting in your `composer.json` config to fake PHP version used for dependency resolving and checks:

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.1.18"
    }
},
```

In this way you can set different PHP version for each project locally without modifying any global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Composer is a PHP script so you can run it's PHAR as argument for php binary, for e.g. if you have php 5.6 in `~/bin/php56` you have to run `~/bin/php56 /path/to/composer.phar install`