# How to automatically switch php versions when cd'ing into another directory bash

Tags: php, bash, composer-php

I have multiple projects that I work on.

Some are on php 7.3, most of 7.4 and a single one on 8.1

Having to switch php everytime when I switch projects is a solution I have now, but sometimes I need to do a quick check on another project, and that breaks code running in another project because the global php are updated.

All my projects are composer based, but composer doesn't "spit out" what the most desired php version is.

How can I based on composer.json/lock detect the correct php version to use?

Comment: I had the same probem. I added two VirtualHost and then in htaccess: SetHandler proxy:unix:/usr/run/uwsgi/fastrouter.sock|uwsgi://php73  .  From time to time I change DocumentDirectory in config of apache.

Comment: I suggest you start using containers (docker). It resolves how can you run multiple applications with different dependencies (e.g. PHP).

Comment: Running magento in containers for development doesn't make a beef laptop happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script is made with php installed via [ppa:ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php). If your php versions are self compiled, and not linked in for example /usr/bin/php7.4 you'll need to modify the paths to the correct paths. This code however does assume the binaries are named `php7.x` or `php8.x`

This also requires that there is a composer installed on your system.

Add the following code to your .bashrc file.(`nano ~/.bashrc`)
Explanations of what does what are in the comments in the code.

```bash
function do_php() {
    # Path where to find the php binaries
    PHPPATH='/usr/bin'
    
    # PHP versions in order of most used
    declare -a phpversions=("7.4" "7.3" "8.1" "8.0" "7.2" "7.1" "7.0");
    # Get a direct path to composer
    composer_path="$(whereis composer | cut -d  ' ' -f 2)"
    # Loop through all php versions
    for phpversion in "${phpversions[@]}"
      do
        PHP=$PHPPATH/php$phpversion
        # If the given php version is installed
        if [ -f $PHP ]; then
          # Check if it matches the requirements
          SUCCESS=$($PHP $composer_path check-platform-reqs 2>/dev/null | grep php | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
           # If we're matching
           if [ "$SUCCESS" == "success" ]; then
              # Run command with given binary
              $PHP "$@"
              # exit function
              return
           fi
         fi
    done
    
    #Nothing matched, just run with default php and let the programmer deal with the issue
    \php "$@"
}

# Set the alias for php to do_php
alias php='do_php'
```

Answer (score 0):

> All my projects are composer based, but composer doesn't "spit out" what the most desired php version is.
>
> How can I based on composer.json/lock detect the correct php version to use?

Well composer itself can not magically tell you what your intend (per project) is, however you can configure this easily on a per-project basis with platform packages. For the PHP version it is the `php` package:

```
{
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.0.3"
        }
    }
}
```

*(Compare: [Composer config platform](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform), [Run composer using different version of PHP without changing the environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52154310/367456))*

You can also add extensions and libraries. Now you have configured the information in your project and composer will use that version when installing and updating dependencies (e.g. for `7.0.3` above, package versions that require `>= 7.0.4` won't install).

7.0.3 is a bad example (just copied the version from Composer docs), let's say you're in a PHP 7.4 project:

```
$ composer config platform.php '7.4.30'
```

It is also now easy to map on the Sury packages binary names, just keep the head:

```
$ composer config platform.php | head -c3
7.4
```

For Composer invocations itself it won't be necessary any longer, however you may want to do other things, so here some hints, that already work within Composer:

- The `@php`  script shortcut (Composer, see *[Executing PHP scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#executing-php-scripts)*)
- The `PHP_BINARY` environment variable (Composer, see same)

Those are all based on the php binary composer is running with. So if you need to inject it, call composer with the adequate php version:

```
$ composer config platform.php '8.1.11'
$ php$(composer config platform.php | head -c3) $(which composer) diagnose
Checking composer.json: OK
...
PHP version: 8.1.11 - Package overridden via config.platform, same as actual
PHP binary path: /usr/bin/php8.1
...
```

*(Example: Composer invocation with Ondřej Surý php8.1 package on Ubuntu)*

So eventual composer scripts/hooks should be covered.

For invocation in general I'd suggest to use a build manager to define targets, their dependencies and the rules how they are made. You should have the `make` utility already on your box and then it is just `make` and done for most of the time. You can add the php executable name to configuration there, control the platform version in `composer.json` and have this even re-useable across projects. no need to add it to the environment when you can have it in the project IMHO (Compare *[Automation and Make](https://swcarpentry.github.io/make-novice/)*).

When it comes the day you start to migrate your project to another php version, you have only one environment. With a build manager you can easily run the same setup with different php versions to check the upgrade path (and even can do this in parallel). Just for the outlook. Keep it simple and stupid, then you have the best options in the long run (and also portability across projects).